# What's the easiest way to check if inputed number is a positive integer and re-prompt if not?

Tags: java, validation

The program takes user input which is supposed to be an integer greater than 0. If the user doesn't do this he is notified of the mistake and is reprompted. Once the correct input is entered, the value is returned. What's the best way to do this? The following code is my try but doesn't work. It seems unnecessarily complex for such an easy task.

```
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer greater than 0:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int red = -1;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            red = scan.nextInt();
        }catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Number must be an integer"); 
            scan.nextLine();
            if(red < 1)
                System.out.println("Number must be more than zero");
            else
                break;
        }
    }while(true);
    return red;
```

Sometimes I don't know what to put in my question because I already know the code doesn't work - so if there's something else I should tell please let me know.

Comment: One of the problems is `nextInt` won't consume the new line character, meaning you will end up in an infinite loop after the first past...And I'm not sure `scananner` is ;)

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is running in the right direction, beware though, `nextInt` won't consume the new line, leaving it within the scanner, meaning you will end up with an infinite loop after the first unsuccessful loop.

Personally, I would simply get the input as a `String` using `nextLine`, which will consume the new line, causing the next loop to stop at the statement.

Then I would simply parse the `String` to an `int` value using `Integer.parseInt`

For example...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int red = -1;
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer greater than 0:");
    String text = scan.nextLine();
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            red = Integer.parseInt(text);
            // This is optional...
            if (red < 1) {
                System.out.println("Number must be more than zero");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            // This is optional...
            System.out.println("Not a number, try again...");
        }
    }
} while (red < 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this class instead of the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` classes to get user input:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Input{
private static BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public static Double getDouble(String prompt){
    Double value;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        value=Double.parseDouble(Input.input.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception error){
        // error condition
        value=null;
    }
    return value;
}
public static Integer getInteger(String prompt){
    Integer value;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        value=Integer.parseInt(Input.input.readLine());
    }
    catch (Exception error){
        // error condition
        value=null;
    }
    return value;
}
public static String getString(String prompt){
    String string;
    System.out.print(prompt);
    try{
        string=Input.input.readLine();
    }
    catch (Exception error){
        // error condition
        string=null;
    }
    return string;
}
}
```

Now, to answer your question u can write your code like this:

```
public class InputTest {


public int checkValue() {

    int value; 
    do {
        value = Input.getInteger("Enter a value greater than 0: ");
    } while (value <= 0);

    return value;

    }
   }
```